# Data structures and algorithms book for the practitioner not for the academic

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

I'm planning to invest some time every week studying data structures and algorithms.
Do you recommend: "MIT Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition" by Cormen, Leiseson, Rivest and Stein?
AFAIK this book is legendary but I don't know its target audience.

Is this book suitable for my purpose? or it is for academic studies? is it loaded with heavy math?

Comment: what language are you going to focus on, there are some really good books dedicated to this topic that are language specific, especially for C, C++ and Java.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop I'm focusing on Java and Clojure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Java I recommend [Algorithms in Java, Parts 1-4 by Robert Sedgewick](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201361205). And the companion book [Algorithms in Java, Part 5: Graph Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201361213).

For general studies I also have the [Introductions to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) books, it is a good general reference. This [Algorithms, Fourth Edition by Robert Sedgewick](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X) looks good as well, but probably covers a lot of stuff already in the previously mentioned books.

For Clojure, you will probably need to get a Functional based Algorithm book. [Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521513383) looks like it might be a good companion to a the more general procedural books.

Comment: lollipop Thanks for mentioning "Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design"

Answer (score 3):

It has a fair amount of math and mathematically oriented material, but most of the math isn't all the "heavy" (though, of course, definitions of "heavy" vary). It is fairly academic -- if your interest is primarily in learning algorithms from a purely practical viewpoint (e.g., what algorithm to apply in a given situation) it may be rather overkill for your purposes (though I don't have an immediate recommendation of anything that's dramatically better for that kind of use either).

Comment: @4bu3li While the book's target audience is clearly academic, it is very well written (very clear, easy to understand, doesn't leave you confused at any point). Also the analysis of each algorithm is "modular", you can skip over most of the math aspects and still get the idea. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

The Algorithm Design Manual by Steve Skiena

You'll probably find this book useful - it has very little emphasis on theory but a lot on the how/what/where/why without delving into too much of math. The author talks about the applications from his experience - so you get to see a practical bent. A light read but a LOT to read!

Comment: This is a very good book for understanding algorithms - http://www.algorist.com/. But the code is written in C language.

Answer (score 2):

Introduction to Algorithms is a very good book. You can read the book and follow the video lecture series available at [AcademicEarth.org](http://www.academicearth.org/courses/introduction-to-algorithms).

But if you want to learn it with a specific language (C, C++ or Java), you can pick any of the data structures and algorithms books by Mark-Allen Weiss, Robert Lafore or Robert Sedgewick.

Answer (score 0):

I read Computer [Algorithms by Horowitz and Sahni](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0716783169), its quite easy to follow with enough examples and pseudo codes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Cormen, I'd recommend reading [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504), if you're using both Java and Clojure.